# ExpressJS node is it possible to call a route function from EJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I am currently working on an Express app which uses EJS for the views. Each view (page) has a corresponding route with a `router.get` function which takes in request and response parameters, and renders the correct view - like so:

```
res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Dashboard' });
```

My question is: is it possible for me to call a function that exists in the route, from the EJS view? (for example within a `button.click` function etc)

So if I have a function in my route (dashboard.js) called deleteRowFromDatabase

```
var deleteRowFromDatabase = function(rowId) {
   //Database logic here
};
```

And then in my view (dashboard.ejs) I want to call this function whenever a user clicks a button

```
$('#deleteButton').click(function() {
        //Call route function somehow here???
    })
```

Is there any way of doing this and if so, how?

Apologies if this question is not worded the best - I am pretty new to Node and Express. 
Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: you cannot. `deleteRowFromDatabase` should be a route and from jquery you can call it using ajax

Comment: thanks for the response! So for every function i wish to call from jquery, I have to first make each of them a route? Wouldn't this get messy if a large number of functions was required?

Comment: if want to comunicate from client to server your server must have the routes that the client can call. NodeJs run on server, jquery on browser

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll look into ajax calls :)